# Derive the step deviation method for mean

Tags: statistics, means

Arithmetic Mean of grouped data can be found by $\bar{x}=\frac{\sum f_ix_i}{\sum f_i}$ where $x_i$ is the midpoint of each class.

Aother equation to evaluate Arithmetic Mean of grouped data is using Step Deviation
$$
\boxed{\bar{x}=a+\frac{\sum f_id_i}{\sum f_i}}
$$
where $a$ is the assumed mean and $d_i=x_i-a$ are the deviations of $x_i$ from the assumed mean, and $N=\sum f_i$

How do I make sense of the second formula which is called the Step Deviation method ?

Is there a proof which shows the above equation actually is the mean ?

Comment: It is just a transformation like $d_i=x_i-a$ for suitable $a$ which gives you mean of the $x_i$s in terms of mean of the $d_i$s.

Comment: @StubbornAtom How do I see this one is actually the mean ?

Comment: Take $x_i=d_i+a$. What do you get as $\bar x$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom thanks, couldnt see it though its that simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanx @StubbornAtom for the hint.
$$
x_i=d_i+a\\
\bar{x}=\frac{\sum f_ix_i}{\sum f_i}=\frac{\sum f_i(d_i+a)}{N}=\frac{\sum f_id_i}{N}+a\frac{\sum f_i}{N}=\frac{\sum f_id_i}{N}+a
$$